# How to I wrap a useState variable in a if statment, but still have it's value be available outside the if reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, use-state

I have the following code I have a `cards` state variable using useState, I have atttempted to add my array above to it, but it just adds an empty array, I wasn't able to put the state inside of the if becuase then my variable was undefined. I tried wrapping everything beflow the state and the state in the if , but the then I get some return issues. So the focus is passing into the `useState(stateReplace)`

Any help would be great

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import { Card } from "./Card";
import update from "immutability-helper";
import { LeadsBuilderCollection } from "../../api/LeadsCollection";
import { useTracker } from "meteor/react-meteor-data";

const style = {
  width: 400,
};
export const Container = ({ params }) => {
  const { leadsBuilder, isLoading } = useTracker(() => {
    const noDataAvailable = { leadsBuilder: [] };

    if (!Meteor.user()) {
      return noDataAvailable;
    }

    const handler = Meteor.subscribe("leadsBuilder");

    if (!handler.ready()) {
      return { ...noDataAvailable, isLoading: true };
    }

    const leadsBuilder = LeadsBuilderCollection.findOne({ _id: params._id });
    return { leadsBuilder };
  });
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  let stateReplace = useMemo(() => {
    if (!isLoading && leadsBuilder?.inputs?.length) {
      leadsBuilder.inputs.map((leadInput, i) => {
        ({ id: i, text: leadInput.name });
      });
    }
    return [];
  }, [isLoading, leadsBuilder]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCards(stateReplace);
  }, [setCards, stateReplace]);

  const moveCard = useCallback(
    (dragIndex, hoverIndex) => {
      const dragCard = cards[dragIndex];
      setCards(
        update(cards, {
          $splice: [
            [dragIndex, 1],
            [hoverIndex, 0, dragCard],
          ],
        })
      );
    },
    [cards]
  );
  const renderCard = (card, index) => {
    return (
      <>
        {isLoading ? (
          <div className="loading">loading...</div>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Card
              key={card.id}
              index={index}
              id={card.id}
              text={card.text}
              moveCard={moveCard}
            />
          </>
        )}
      </>
    );
  };
  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <div className="loading">loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <>
          <div style={style}>{cards.map((card, i) => renderCard(card, i))}</div>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Update: I can get it to run if I place a setState in a useEffect but then I get a warning and the drag and drop doesnt work

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setCards(stateReplace);
  });
```

`Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.`

Update #2

```
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  let stateReplace = useMemo(() => {
    console.log("memo");
    if (!isLoading && leadsBuilder?.inputs?.length) {
      return leadsBuilder.inputs.map((leadInput, i) => {
        ({ id: i, text: leadInput.name });
      });
    }
    return [];
  }, [isLoading]);

  console.log(stateReplace);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCards(stateReplace);

    console.log(setCards);
  }, [setCards, stateReplace]);
```

current output

```
(4) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
memo
cannot read propery `id`
```

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    setCards(stateReplace);
  }, [setCards]);

Comment: I tried `useEffect(() => {
    setCards(stateReplace);
  }, [setCards]);` and nothing shows up, if I remove the setCards at the end it workds but gfet the error seen above in my update

Comment: you should have setCards in moveCard useCallback dependency array

Comment: Unforuntaley I am not exactly sure what you mean by that, or what that implies I should do.

Comment: useEffect(() => {     setCards(stateReplace);   }, [setCards, stateReplace]);   you don't react on stateRepalce changes... just. but this is not op. you should memo this value in useMemo bacause it will change on every reander so it will be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would do it like that

```
//for preveting updates of memo if ledsBulder will changes on each render
const leadsBuilderRef = useRef(leadsBuilder)

let stateReplace = useMemo(()=>{
  if (!isLoading && leadsBuilder.current?.inputs?.length) {
    return leadsBuilder.current.inputs.map((leadInput, i) => {
      return { id: i, text: leadInput.name };
    });
  }
  return []
}, [isLoading, leadsBuilderRef]);
```

and  then

```
useEffect(() => {
   setCards(stateReplace);
}, [setCards, stateRepalce]);
```

Comment: I posted my entire code for clarity and added in your part, and still get this error `Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.`

Comment: @AndersKitson is this happen in useEffect ?? check it by comment setState in useEffect

Comment: `State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the " + 'second callback argument. To execute a side effect after ' + 'rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect()` Also nothing is rendered either

Comment: man. like it is write state don't have callback so don't put it.

Comment: put console.log in let stateReplace = useMemo(() => {console.log("memo").....) this will allow you to check if useMemo starts with every render

Comment: yeah memo, just keeps rerendering

Comment: probably lead Builder is changing on each render,

Comment: yeah that's where I am stuck because I am checking if leadsBuilder array is empy and isLoading is done in the if statment, because I am using useTracker and Meter.subscribe and I think meteor just keeps checking for data. But I couldn't wrap the useState in my if statement to prevent the rerender, because then the variable was unavailab outside

Comment: you can't use hooks in if statements. Only call Hooks at the top level. Don't call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.  Try useReference use memo don't react on value changes in referance objects. so if you will store it in refrence then it will only react on isLoding changes.

Comment: Ok I remove the leadsBuilder from the dependency array and added a return to the leadsBuilder.inputs.map that was missing. I will add this code above with the results I am getting.

Comment: you have to prevent useMemo for changes value on each render so you can do it by using reference. (yeap was missing return in map)

Comment: you still don't return nothing from map !! :)